# How to grep a line starting with an single quote , alphabet followed by fixed digit only?

Tags: shell, grep

I wish to grep a line staring which start with Alphabet followed by 5 numbers.

MY approach is
eg

```
'A12345'
'A123456'


output should be only line starting with Alphabet followed by 5 numbers 

ie 'A12345'

 My approach : it doesn't work 
 grep -E '[A-Z]''[0-9]{5}'
```

Comment: I think you want `grep -E "^[A-Z][0-9]{5}$`

Comment: @Sundeep Those number are inside single quote and how can I achieve a same grep with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
# PCRE allows \xHH escapes
$ grep -P '^\x27[A-Z][0-9]{5}\x27' ip.txt
'A12345'

# double quotes can also be used here since there's no clash
$ grep -E "^'[A-Z][0-9]{5}'" ip.txt
'A12345'

# this is same as ^' followed by [A-Z][0-9]{5} and then another '
$ grep -E "^'"'[A-Z][0-9]{5}'"'" ip.txt
'A12345'
```

Here's an example where double quotes can be problematic. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes and [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash) for more details.

```sh
$ echo '1a$(z)b' | grep -E "a$(z)b"
z: command not found
```

Comment: Thank you Sandeep , incase if I have two string , each is inside a single quote in a line .  It doesn't grep anything . Can you please tell me what that reason could be ...  eg in a line if I have such string  'A12345' 'A12345'

Comment: I can't guess what could fail unless you show the exact commands you tried. And I don't know what kind of variations in input you can have. It is better to ask a new question and use code formatting properly which is difficult to do in comments.

Comment: @yamut - Add `o` flag then: `grep -Eo '[A-Z][0-9]{5}'`

Comment: @Sundeep I have created a new question , can you please have a look at it.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67926274/how-to-grep-a-line-containing-a-string-enclosed-in-single-quote